# How to scroll the page using NestedScrollView to a given position. AndroidStudio

Tags: android, scroll

> How to scroll the page using NestedScrollView to a given position.
> I have a NestedScrollView which I set onCreateView to binding.NestedScrollView.scrollto(0,100) but nothing happens. How to fix it?

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

      binding.scrollView2.scrollTo(0,100)
}
```

and this the NestedScrollView:

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/toolbar3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            ...

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your NestedScrollView has 0 width and 0 height so it's simply invisible. I suggest you changing it both to match_parent. Also `LinearLayout` inside your scrollview should has `wrap_content` height:

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/toolbar3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        ...

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

And then to scroll use this:

```
scrollView2.post({
   binding.scrollView2.scrollTo(0,100);
});
```

Comment: binding.scrollView2.post({
            binding.scrollView2.scrollTo(0,100);
        })

Comment: I did as you said but nothing happened when loading the page(

Comment: share your xml layout so we can take a look

Comment: i added above in question

Comment: I've edited my answer. Take a look.

Comment: unfortunately it did not solve my problem

Comment: What does this line mean scrollView2.post({ . If this is a call to the scrollView object, why is there no binding

Comment: can i ask you for a working example